# Stack implementation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, stack

I am implementing a stack in Objective-C, when I'm testing my class, I get invalid results.
Here are the codes:

Classes/Stack.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define DEFAULT_SIZE 16

@interface Stack : NSObject {
    @private int size;
    @private int top;
    @private NSMutableArray* arr;
}

- (id) init;
- (id) initWithSize: (int) size;

- (void) push: (id) element;
- (id)   pop;

- (id) peek;

- (int) size;

- (BOOL) isEmpty;

@end
```

Classes/Stack.m:

```
#import "Stack.h"

@implementation Stack

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        size = DEFAULT_SIZE;
        top = 0;
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id) initWithSize: (int) aSize {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        if(aSize <= 0)
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Invalid Argument" reason:@"Size should be strictly positive." userInfo:nil];

        size = aSize;
        top = 0;
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) push: (id) element {
    if(top > size)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Illegal State" reason:@"Stack contents exceed the valid limit." userInfo:nil];

    if(top == size)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Stack Overflow" reason:@"Stack is full, can not push any element." userInfo:nil];

    [arr addObject:element];
    top++;
}

- (id) pop {
    if(top < 0)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Illegal State" reason:@"Stack lower limit is invalid." userInfo:nil];

    if(top == 0)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Stack Underflow" reason:@"Stack is empty, can not pop any element" userInfo:nil];

//    id ret = [arr lastObject];
//    [arr removeLastObject];
//    top--;

    id ret = [arr objectAtIndex:(--top)];

    return ret;
}

- (id) peek {
    if(top < 0)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Illegal State" reason:@"Stack lower limit is invalid." userInfo:nil];

    if(top == 0)
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Stack Underflow" reason:@"Stack is empty, can not pop any element" userInfo:nil];

//    return [arr lastObject];
    return [arr objectAtIndex:(top - 1)];
}

- (int) size {
    return top;
}

- (BOOL) isEmpty {
    return top == 0;
}

@end
```

and main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Classes/Stack.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Stack* stack = [[Stack alloc] initWithSize:3];

        [stack push:@"world"];
        [stack push:@" "];
        [stack push:@"hello"];


        for(int i = 0; i < [stack size]; i++)
            NSLog(@"%@", [stack pop]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
2014-01-07 00:09:36.045 Data Structures[9210:303] hello
2014-01-07 00:09:36.047 Data Structures[9210:303]  
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Is there something wrong with my code and producing invalid results?

Comment: why you need `top`? just use `arr.count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's walk through the loop.

#### Iteration 1:

```
i == 0
[stack size] == 3
```

#### Iteration 2:

```
i == 1
[stack size] == 2
```

#### Iteration 3:

```
i == 2
[stack size] == 1
```

So the loop stops before the third iteration.

You want your loop to look like one of the following:

```
int stackSize = [stack size];
for (int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++)
    NSLog(@"%@", [stack pop]);
}
```

or

```
while ([stack size] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [stack pop]);
}
```

Incidentally, as a couple of others have pointed out, you don't really need `top` — it's just a duplicate of your array's count. But the same logic error would appear in the loop even with that change.